# openpyxl if cell has background color, based on conditional_formatting

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I want to get cells that are highlighted based on conditional formatting, which has been done in a different python file.

```py
for sheet in wb.worksheets:
    for i in range(sheet.max_column - 1):
        num = i + 2
        taisei = sheet.cell(row=526, column=num).fill.bgColor.value
        taisei2 = sheet.cell(row=527, column=num).fill.bgColor.value
        kaifuku = sheet.cell(row=528, column=num).fill.bgColor.value
        seichou = sheet.cell(row=529, column=num).fill.bgColor.value


        if taisei != "00000000" and taisei2 != '00000000':
            row = sheet1.max_row + 1
            sheet1.cell(row=row, column=1).value = sheet.title
            sheet1.cell(row=row, column=2).value = sheet.cell(
                row=532, column=num).value
        if kaifuku != '00000000':
            row = sheet2.max_row + 1
            sheet2.cell(row=row, column=1).value = sheet.title
            sheet2.cell(row=row, column=2).value = sheet.cell(
                row=532, column=num).value
        if seichou != '00000000':
            row = sheet3.max_row + 1
            sheet3.cell(row=row, column=1).value = sheet.title
            sheet3.cell(row=row, column=2).value = sheet.cell(
                row=532, column=num).value
```

If the code was working correctly, some of the cells would be in a new Excel file, none of them are. Also the background should be `CCFF00` but is `00000000`

Comment: The short answer is that a cell with fill colour from CF is not the same as the fill applied to the cell using 'Format Cells' --> 'Fill', i.e. the Fill property of that cell will not return a fill colour since it's not what is applying the colour.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment to your question, the cell fill does not reflect the fill colour of a cell when its filled by Condition Format.
Also you should probably be looking at the `'fgColor'` not `'bgColor'` for the fill colour anyway.
To obtain the fill colour applied by CF you can try using the VBA function `'DisplayFormat.Interior.Color'`.
This function is does not show as a cell property in Openpyxl I don't see that it can be easily obtained using that Module. However it is easily included if you [can] use Xlwings instead, using the Xlwings API.

As an example I have put together the following code sample to show;
The sheet has 5 cells in column A from rows 2 to 6. The first 4 cells where values start with `'CF'` are filled by a Conditional Format rule, the cell in row 6 with value `'E'` is filled by
`Format Cells --> Fill`.
Columns D and E show the Hex and RGB formats of the colour values used to fill the cells by CF or cell fill.
The value in column B is that returned by `DisplayFormat.Interior.Color` and Column C is that value converted to its Hex equivalent.
As you can see the property returns the correct colour value for the cells with CF and the format cell fill.

Note the value returned by `DisplayFormat.Interior.Color` is a float which is converted to int when assigned to `cf_colour`, if its not converted to float there it would need to be cast when converting to hex in the function. The code includes the casting.

```
import xlwings as xw


def conv_excel_colour(in_colour):
    hex_col = hex(int(in_colour))

    if len(hex_col[2:]) < 6:
        hex_col = f'0{hex_col[2:]}'

    ### Hex value needs to be split every 2 chars and recombined in reverse to obtain correct RGB hex values
    return ''.join([hex_col[i:i + 2] for i in range(0, len(hex_col), 2)][::-1])[:6].upper()


xlfile = 'CF_example.xlsx'
with xw.App(visible=False) as app:
    wb = xw.Book(xlfile)
    sheet = wb.sheets('Sheet1')

    mr = sheet.range('A' + str(wb.sheets[0].cells.last_cell.row)).end('up').row

    for c in range(2, mr):
        c_cell = sheet.range(c, 1)
        cf_colour = int(c_cell.api.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color)
        sheet.range(c, 2).value = cf_colour
        sheet.range(c, 3).value = conv_excel_colour(cf_colour)

    wb.save(f'out_{xlfile}')
```

[image: Example Output]

[xlwings](/questions/tagged/xlwings)